# Lottery scenario with different odds for multiple outcomes

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, games

There are 21 chances to achieve six outcomes, ranging from most desirable to sixth most desirable.

There are six players. Player 1 has 6 of 21 chances to attain the most desirable outcome. Player 2 has 5 chances, Player 3 has 4 chances, Player 4 has 3 chances, Player 5 has 2 chances, Player 6 has 1 chance for a total of 21 chances.

I think I know what the chances are that Player 1 attains the most desirable outcome, but I'm curious about the other outcomes. With those odds, what is the probability that each player can attain each outcome? Am I overthinking this? What is the appropriate formula or model?

Bear in mind that I need an answer that accounts for my level of knowledge on the subject, which you should assume is that of a high school student ca. 2010.